# How to convert a Pivot table back to original format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have created a pivot table out of movielens dataset.

How can I convert this pivot table back to original dataset?

The unstack() function doesn't give the desired output.

The image of pivot table:

[image: The image of pivot table]

The image of what the converted dataset should look like:

[image: The image of what the converted dataset should look like]

```html
#Read Movielens dataset
    df_ratings = pd.read_csv('/home/neera/DataSets/ml-latest-small/ratings.csv')

#Code used to create the pivot table
    user_movie_ratings = pd.pivot_table(ratings_title, index='userId', columns= 
    'movieId', values='rating')
```

Comment: Please show an example of the original table, preferably by writing code which creates some portion of it

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216978/pandas-how-to-unpivot-a-pivot-table) and see if it leads you to your desired result.

Comment: @VasilisD I added the code I used to read the csv file and convert to pivot table

Comment: @d_kennetz that helped. Thank You.

Comment: @Neera, could you please post the examples as code, not images?

Comment: Problem is solved by @d

Comment: pd.wide_to_long is normally what I use for this